# Page format errors

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Name}" />
 <br />
 <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Description__c}" />
 <br />
 <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.ContactID__c}" />
 <apex:outputText value="test" />
```

It is causing this to occur. Changing the amount of columns does madness, the column is spanning 2 columns which causes this to occur. Anyone familiar with it enough to know what a workaround fix on this is? Or am i going to have to override with a css file.

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" title="Loan Detail">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" value="Delete"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Name}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Description__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.ContactID__c}" id="cid"/>
        <apex:outputText value="test" id="cidtext" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.LoanType__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.LoanStartDate__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Term__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.MaturityDate__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.TemplateID__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.PaymentFrequency__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.CalculationMethod__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.CalculationType__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Compounding__c}" />    
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.CalculationDay__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.AmortizationPeriod__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.PaymentAmount__c}" />    
        <br />    
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.Funded__c}" />     
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.LastInvoiceDate__c}" />
        <br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Loan__c.NextInvoiceDate__c}" />                                               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire block of output?  E.g. can you paste the entire pageblock element if you are using one?

Comment: added it to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the <br> right after:

```
<apex:outputText value="test" id="cidtext" />
```

The pageBlockSection is smart enough to wrap after 2 elements per row.

Comment: Where Test is i want that to remain there but i want the next parts to wrap back towards the left. So LoanType would be under Borrower. And the `outputtext` would be left floating right.

Comment: I've updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it works?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="1">
.....
....

<!-- all stuff -->
....
</apex:pageblockSection>
```